# Is there a way to appear offline in Trello?

Tags: trello

Often in the weekends or at night, I will login to Trello to look at what tasks I have left and what I need to do or research over the weekends. However, I don't want to let my boss know that I'm online, looking at the Trello board.

Is there a way to have some privacy and surf Trello appearing offline to everyone?

Comment: I'm not going to post it as an answer because I'm not certain its true, but if you use the iPhone app it might not make you appear active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please email us at feature-ideas@trello.com about this if this is important to you. When it reaches a certain level of traffic, we'll add it to the development board at http://trello.com/dev

The answer right now is that you can't control how you appear online.